# type casting with objects

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to convert two objects to integers, add them, and then convert them back to objects and store them in an Object array. I when I try adding the Objects back into the array, though, I get an Array Store Exception.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = scanner.nextLine();
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " "); 
Object[] numbersArray = Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")).toArray();
str = scanner.nextLine();
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " "); 
Object[] translateArray = Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")).toArray();

for (int i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i+=2) {
     Object x = (Object) (Integer.parseInt(numbersArray[i].toString()) 
                   + Integer.parseInt(translateArray[0].toString()));
     Object y = (Object) (Integer.parseInt(numbersArray[(i+1)].toString()) 
                   + Integer.parseInt(translateArray[1].toString()));

     System.out.println(x.getClass().getName()); //how is this an integer???
     System.out.println(y); //values get added correctly...
     numbersArray[i] = (Object) x;
     numbersArray[i+1] = (Object) y;
  }
```

As you can probably see, I am trying to cast the Object type everywhere I can, but numbersArray refuses to take it. I think my problem has something to do with the assignment statements of Objects x and y. Why are they still coming up as integers?

Comment: What is the result  you're expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numbersArray` is really a `String[]`. This is because `String.split()` returns a `String[]` and `Arrays.asList(array).toArray()` works by simply calling `clone()` on the wrapped array.

As a result, when you try to store an `Integer` in the `String[]` you get an `ArrayStoreException`.

If you want to get a true `Object[]` you can do

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" "));
Object[] numbersArray = list.toArray(new Object[list.size()]);
```

However, I would consider changing your design. Using an `Object[]` first to store `String`s and then `Integer`s is likely to cause confusion and bugs.

Comment: The real culprit here is that arrays in Java are covariants.

Comment: I agree. If I could go back in time and change that I definitely would.

Comment: This might be considered a flaw of the API. `List.toArray()` should return an `Object[]` (and not a subtype of), otherwise there is no way to, as the javadoc claims, "The caller is thus free to modify the returned array"

Comment: @bayou.io in fact, `Whatever[]` is `Object[]` because that's how arrays in Java are defined, so the current implementation of `toArray` is compliant. This is more like a flaw in the design of the language .

Comment: Arrays are evil and should be punished. `LinkedLists`, `ArrayLists`, anything that implements the `List` interface. Old Arrays are no longer necessary.

Comment: It depends on the definition of `is`:) The javadoc implies that is is a modifiable `Object[]`, therefore user ought to be able to insert Object in it.

Comment: `type java.awt.List does not take parameters`

Comment: @trembling You should import `java.lang.List` not `java.awt.List`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington `java.util.List`

Answer (score 1):

since Paul has answered your main question ,let me answer your sub question

> System.out.println(x.getClass().getName()); //how is this an
>   integer???

if you run the following simple code :

```
Object o = 45;
System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
```

it will give you `java.lang.Integer` because the reference maybe  of type `Object` but the actual value is a `Integer`.